# Are questions asking which technologies contain a certain feature off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Are questions asking something like "Do any game engines support feature X out of the box?" off-topic? Or do these fall under the "which technology to use" category (or some other category)?

Comment: This question is posted because of this question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87750/do-any-game-engines-support-2d-shape-rendering-using-b%c3%a9zier-paths-and-polygons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual question is a yes-or-no question, which we know to be bad. The implied follow up is "okay, which engines support this technology?" which is, I'd argue, pretty clearly a "which technology" question.

But even if you disagree with that, it's a list-generation question, which is too broad.

So I think we should close these.

Answer (score 6):

I think these questions are tricky and should be handled on a case-by-case basis, but should be closed more often than remain open.

First of all, because the answer can very easily be "No", which doesn't make for a very good answer. Or they can be "No, but you could try...", which can easily get into a back and forth about how you might tweak technology Y to work for feature X. Or generate a list of plugins or libraries that add said feature to a specific technology.

I think it'll be less likely for the answer to be "Yes, technology A and B support it and no others". This would be a very definite answer and likely pretty rare.

Since I see far more of the answers being the wishy-washy type, I don't think these questions are a good fit for the site.

Comment: I wonder what actually would be a good way to find out which existing frameworks support feature X? Should one ask for each framework separately? In other words: Would "Does framework X support feature Y?" questions be offtopic?

Comment: In that case I believe it would be best to look up the documentation. Yes-or-no questions are not very good questions.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, these questions are not good QA site questions for the same reason [shopping](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping) questions aren't allowed on SuperUser.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

> [T]echnology moves so rapidly that the best shopping recommendations will be utterly obsolete within a year! What’s the point of a bunch of labor intensive questions that provide only temporary benefit to a limited (some might say Too Localized) audience? There isn’t any.

Comment: Yes, technology moves often rapidly but still, even a temporary benefit for a limited audience is a benefit. I think one should not be too harsh and decide on a case by case basis. After all every question is only useful to a limited audience and might become outdated. Most questions here are about technology one way or the other.