# How do we feel in regards to questions that ask if a certain piece of technology is capable of a certain feature?

Tags: discussion, questions

How do we feel in regards to questions that ask if a certain piece of technology is capable of a certain feature?

I am sure I already found a relevant meta discussion, in which we discussed this in regards to being a "opinion-based" or "what technology should I use" question. However, for the life of me, I can not find it, now. I am sure I favourited it, but it seems I have cleaned out my favourites, since. I tend to do that from time to time, as articles appear less relevant.

The answer I read, which seemed logical and actually changed my viewpoint, briefly stated that these specific questions were okay; provided it gave an absolute set of requirements.

- The question would not be a "which technology to use" question, because the user is not asking "which technology to use". They have already found the technology they wish to use, and rather, would like to clarify if it is capable of certain requirements they have.
- The question is not opinion-based, *provided there is a specific set of requirements that allow absolute answers*. For example, "does this technology support efficient workflow" would not allow for an absolute answer, as it comes down to each individuals interpretation of efficiency, and comparison to other systems. "Does this system allow for 3D graphics" *does* allow absolute answers; it either does, or it doesn't. As such, this specific set of requirements was proposed as a heavy requirement for such questions, *or at least, as far as I can remember*.

Regardless, this all makes sense, to me. Before reading this previous article, I would have swayed against *all* questions that asked if a certain technology was capable of a certain feature. In cases I have encountered, these questions could still be considered *poor quality* due to a lack of research, but *lack of research* is not a valid close reason.

Note that this is very different to [asking for a *list* of *all* technologies featuring a specific feature](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/are-questions-asking-which-technologies-contain-a-certain-feature-off-topic).

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I merged this question with its duplicate to move @DMGregory's answer over there as well. It also merged the comments.